# How to install httplib library inside CentOS based container

Tags: installation, yum

I am trying to install `https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib` inside a **container** (CentOS based). I use this command:

`yum install cpp-httplib`

but it says that the `package is not found`. Similar command works for me for `https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp`

`yum install jsoncpp`

What am I missing?

Comment: Its not necessarily in the repository - I don't have a centos based system, but what happens when you 'yum search cpp-httplib' ?

Comment: It says ```Warning: No matches found for: cpp-httplib
No matches found```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package repositories are not universal - they contain repositories various contributors have packaged.

What you're 'missing' is that while libraries are *commonly* packaged in a repository, this one isn't.

I'm not a dev so I can't go into the details, but I believe you can pull the appropriate files from the git repo for your project instead and use those.